# R: export PDF with diacritical marks

Tags: r, pdf, export

I have a problem with export to PDF. In RGui graph's labels every diacritical marks are OK. When I export this to JPG, PNG, or windows metafile, diacritical marks are still OK. 
But export to PDF change every diacritical character to simple character. For example:
ě -> e
š -> s

Does someone know, where is the problem? Thanks.

```
pdf("C:\\...\\awesome-graph.pdf", width=8, height=8)
...
dev.off()
```

Comment: `cairo_pdf` sometimes offers a quick fix <untested>

Comment: Hey it's working. Thanks a lot!